# Boundedness of continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

I am trying to prove:

Suppose that  $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ and that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$$

Prove that f is bounded on $\Bbb{R}$

So far I have said $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ implies f is bounded on $\Bbb{R}$ and that there exists an $M$ such that, for all $x$ in $\Bbb{R}$, |f(x)| $\le$ $M$.

I achieved this by manipulating the definition I was given. I'm unsure if this proves boundedness or if I need to say more.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Continuity on $\Bbb R$ does not imply boundedness. But continuity on a an interval $[-M,M]$ does. In your set-up, you can choose $M$ so that $|f|\le1$ on $[-M,M]^C$.  From this, you can deduce your wanted result.

Comment: Can you explain why |f|≤1 please? I have also never seen the $[-M,M]^c$ notation before. Thank you.

Comment: For an example of a continuous function that is not bounded, consider $f(x) = x$.

Comment: $[-M,M]^C=(-\infty,-M)\cup (M,\infty)$. Use your limit conditions to show that if $M>0$ is large enough, then $|f(x)|\le 1$ for $|x|> M$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that the fact that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ means that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.  Consider $f(x)=x$, for example.  However, a continuous function is bounded on any compact subset.

The trick for this question is to divide $\mathbb{R}$ into three parts, and show that $f$ is bounded on each of them.

For the first part, we use the fact that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.  By definition, there must be some $N$ such that
$$\forall x>N\, \left(\vert f(x) \vert<1\right).$$
(This is the usual definition of a limit with $\epsilon=1$.) Thus, $f$ is bounded (by $-1$ and $1$) on $(N,\infty)$.

Likewise, we can find an $M$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(-\infty,M)$.

All that remains is the part of $\mathbb{R}$ between $M$ and $N$.  So, how can we show that $f$ is bounded on $[M,N]$?

Comment: Using continuity? f must be bounded on a closed interval [M-1, N-1]?

Comment: To show that $f$ is bounded on $[M,N]$, you need to use continuity, together with an important property of the interval $[M,N]$...  Hint: It's a property that it does not share with the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: The fact it is a closed interval?

Comment: Close, but $(-\infty,\infty)$ is also closed.  You're on the right track though.

Comment: This seems to tie in with maximum and minimum values on [a,b]. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed.  $[M,N]$ is both closed and bounded (which, in this setting is the same thing as being *compact*).  You should have a theorem about continuous functions (like $f$) on bounded closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

What you "said" so far is not true. That $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ does not imply $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$.

*Hint*: Since $f$ is continuous, can you prove it is bounded on any closed interval $[a,b]$?

*Hint 2*: You must prove that $f$ is bounded. For that, you can use the continuity of $f$ and the limit of $f$. Try to write down (in an edit to your question) the exact definition of what it means for $f$ to have a limit as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ were not bounded. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset\mathbb R$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n)|=\infty$. If $(x_n)$ were unbounded, it had a divergent subsequence, $(x_{n_k})_k$ say, $|x_{n_k}|\to\infty$, and we had $\lim_{k\to\infty}|f(x_{n_k})|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n)|=\infty$, contradicting your assumption $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=0$. Hence $(x_n)$ is bounded. Thus, it has a convergent subsequence, $(x_{n_l})_l$, say, with limit $x\in\mathbb R$. By continuity, $\lim_{l\to\infty}|f(x_{n_l})|=|f(x)|<\infty$, but $\lim_{l\to\infty}|f(x_{n_l})|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n)|=\infty$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be given. From $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and as $x \rightarrow -\infty$, we know there exists $N$ s.t. for all $|x| \geq N$,
$$ |f(x)| \leq \varepsilon.$$ Since $f$ is continuous, by extreme value theorem, there exists $M$ s.t. for all $x \in [-N,N]$,
$$ |f(x)| \leq M.$$ Therefore, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ f(x) \leq \max(M,\varepsilon).$$